# how to suppress the fig numbering in caption with tufte package?

Tags: captions, tufte

How can I suppress caption number with `tufte` package ? 
I've tried with `caption` package, but don't work with `tufte` ...
Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome, do you want to suppress the numbering for *all* or just single captions?

Comment: I want to suppress the numbering for all captions !

Comment: Do you want a \listoffigures?  If not, don't use \caption.  Just center some text.

Comment: As I don't need a \listoffigures, the "don't use caption" is just what I need ! I've also tried the \usepackage{ccaption} and the \legend option, good job too.Thanks for all your solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following lines in your preamble

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\fnum@figure{\figurename}
\makeatother
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\fnum@figure{\figurename}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

If you want the same behavior for tables, as well, add also

```
\renewcommand\fnum@table{\tablename}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\fnum@figure{\figurename}
\renewcommand\fnum@table{\tablename}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\caption{A table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]